# Why can you create a struct with temporary values but not assign it to one?

Tags: rust

I created two structs containing references and assigned them temporary values constructed from static str's. They seem to be equivalent, but one works and the other one does not.

given:

```
struct bar<'a>{
    a : &'a String
}

struct foo<'a>{
    a: &'a mut bar<'a>
}
```

why does

```
let x = foo{a: &mut bar{a:& "something".to_string()}};
```

work and

```
*x.a = poi{a:& "something else".to_string()};
println!("{}",x.a.a);
```

later does not?